# HTML Email for Outlook 2011

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm working on an HTML email and for some reason the year under the "quarterly new commitments" are all bunched up and I'm not sure how to fix it. There should be a year under each graph. This is not working on outlook 2011 and I would like to get it to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is a screenshot of the image:

[image: email screenshot]

This is the code:

```
<head>
<h1>Five Year Giving</h1>
<div class='tab_detail'>
<h3>Quarterly New Commitments</h3>
</head><img src="http://web.mit.edu/odrs/Public/rd_utilities/images/block_new_red_1px.gif" alt=""
  title="<<fy_quarter>> $<<tot_ngnp_formatted>> (<<N>> donors)"  border="1" height="<<ngnp_pxl>>" width="5"><img src="http://web.mit.edu/odrs/Public/rd_utilities/images/block_gray_1px.gif" alt=""
  border="0" height="0" width="<<spacer>>"><foot>
  <br>
 <div style="position: relative;">
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy5_label>></span>
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy4_label>></span>
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy3_label>></span>
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy2_label>></span>
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy1_label>></span>
   <span style="position: fixed; left: 50 px; size: -1;"><<fy0_label>></span>
 </div>
 <br>
 <p>
</foot>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that your span positions are all fixed at the same point. You probably need to change them to relative, or increment the left: values to spread the labels out. In either case, this layout will probably fail in a lot of email clients, since divs are notoriously unreliable for layout control in email. You would be better off using a table to place the labels.